# Mocking a class in a Flask API

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I have three files

**helper.py**

```
class helper:
    def __init__(self, out_file):
    self.out_file = out_file
    def foo(first, second):
        # Write data to file
```

**flask_API.py**

```
from helper import helper

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def parse_request():
    content = request.get_json()

    out_file = #based on timestamp

    helper(out_file).foo(content['first'], content['second'])
```

**test_flask.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import flask_API

class testFlaskAPI(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = flask_API.app.test_client()
        self.app.test = True

    @patch('flask_API.app.helper', return_value=None)
    def test_service(self, mock_helper):
        response = self.app.post(base_url, data=json.dumps({"some":"value"}, content_type='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I am having trouble mocking the helper class. This gives me an error saying

```
AttributeError: <Flask 'flask_API'> does not have the attribute 'helper'
```

I read that a class/method needs to be mocked where it is being called instead of where it's defined. Is there something wrong with the way I am patching the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the solution turned out to be fairly simple. First there was no need to add `app` in the `@patch` decorator. The test just needed `@patch('flask_API.helper')`. Second, I first needed to return the mock of the class and then mock the function call as well. So the final answer turned out to be

```
@patch('flask_API.helper')
def test_service(self, mock_helper):

    mocking_helper = mock_helper.return_value  # mocking the class
    mocking_helper.foo.return_value = None

    response = self.app.post(base_url, data=json.dumps({"some":"value"}, content_type='application/json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```